# Smoothness of Minkowski functional is equivalent to smoothness of boundary

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, gt.geometric-topology, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

Let $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex body containing $0$ in its interior.  I recently read that  Minkowski functional of $C$,
$$
f_C(x):=\inf\Big\{t>0:\frac1{t}\cdot x\in C\Big\},
$$
is $C^1$ if and only if $C$ has a $C^1$-boundary.  However, I can't find a reference for this; would someone happen to know one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that since you are on a finite dimensional space, the Minkowski functional yields a norm. For this norm the boundary of the convex body is the unit sphere. Now the differentiability condition for the boundary is equivalent to asking the unit sphere to be a $C^1$-submanifold.

Now on a Banach space a norm is (off 0) $k$- times continuously differentiable If and only If its unit sphere is a $C^k$-submanifold.
A reference for this result is for example Theorem 13.14 in Kriegl and Michors  "The convenient setting of global Analysis". Available for free here [1](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/apbookh-ams.pdf).

Comment: It's only a norm when the domain is balanced I think.

Comment: That is correct and was not mentioned in my answer. One should recheck the proof but from the top of my head it does not use the norm property in the step in an integral way.

Comment: Yes, that seems reasonable to me.